# Livewire form not working when page is visited through wire:navigate

Tags: laravel, components, laravel-livewire, handle

I have a simple login page which is a full-page livewire component. The component includes public "login" method which handles the user login.

When the page is directly loaded on the browser, or the page is refreshed (I mean default browser page load) no problem occurs and the form works fine. But if I visit the page through a "wire:navigate" link (I mean if the page is loaded with livewire handle through javascript) the form doesn't work and gives the following error:

> livewire.esm.js:7370 Uncaught (in promise) Component not found: ivTMLIaWf9gJDQPEyMMK

The problem also occurs with live models.

Thanks for the answers.

Edit: The form works fine even if with wire:navigate if I remove other components from the page. Note that all components have unique keys.

Edit: The problem seems to be caused by x-persist. Some other elements on the page had x-persist attribute. When I remove x-persist from the elements, everything started to work fine. So is this a bug to be reported or is there a solution for this problem?